# How to re-order an array of objects based on several conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I'm trying to use the `Array.prototype.sort()` method to reorder an array or objects.

My array of objects may look something like (I have removed irrelevant properties from the real life scenario):

```
[
    {
        context: [
            { value: 'hover' }
        ]
    },
    {
        context: []
    },
    {
        context: [
            { value: 'active' }
        ]
    },
    {
        context: [
            { value: 'large' }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to re-order the objects based on the values contained within the nested objects of the `context` property.

The conditions are:

- If there are no context objects, move to beginning of array
- If context object contains a `hover` value, move to the end of the array

So the above array of 4 objects should be re-ordered from `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to `[2, 3, 4, 1]`

I can satisfy the first condition with something like:

```
rules.sort((a, b) => {
    return (a.context.length - b.context.length);
});
```

...which re-orders the array based on the number of context objects (thus satisfying the first condition), but I can't figure out how to get the second condition satisfied.

I'm able to determine if either `a` or `b` arrays contain a context object with a `hover` value, which feels like a good start, but I'm not sure where to go from here...

```
rules.sort((a, b) => {
    const AIsHover  = a.context.some(c => c.value === 'hover');
    const BIsHover  = b.context.some(c => c.value === 'hover');

    return (a.context.length - b.context.length);
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that simply by distinguishing the cases:

```js
rules.sort((a, b) => {
    if (!a.context.length && !b.context.length) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (a.context.length && !b.context.length) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (!a.context.length && b.context.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.context.some(c => c.value === 'hover') && b.context.some(c => c.value === 'hover')) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (a.context.some(c => c.value === 'hover')) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (b.context.some(c => c.value === 'hover')) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to switch the `1`s to `-1`s and vice versa, but it seems to do the trick! Thanks